# Pabbly connect, Jira + Google calendar integration

Tags: google-calendar-api, jira, integration

I have 10 workflows in pabbly, 10 Calendar connections, and one Jira Atlassian account. My question is, In one Jira account I have 10 team members each of them has their own tasks. I created 10 workflows in Pabbly for 10 teammates and they have connected their calendars in each workflow. So when an issue is created in Jira means that time an event will be created in Google Calendar this is the automation process in Pabbly Connect. In this, When I create a task in Jira in my name, then the event is created in all other teammates' calendars. I don't want this automation like this, I need to do it when a task is assigned in my name in Jira means the event need to be created in my calendar only not all my teammates' calendar.

The integration should be straighten off, while I create an issue in my teammate's name in Jira that issue is creating an event in all my teammates' Google calendars. I want to filter it when I create an issue in my teammate's name, For example, if I create an issue in the name of Amber in Jira then the event should be created only in Amber's Google calendar not all my teammates' calendars.